# How to save follower data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table `user_followers` that has: `user_id` and `follower_id`

I'm trying to save a new record where the logged in user follows another user via AJAX.

this is the button:

```
<%= link_to "Add friend", teste_user_follower_path(:params => @friend.id), remote: true, class: 'btn' %>
```

And the action `teste` where I try to save:

```
def teste

if params[:query]
  @friend = User.where(id: params[:query]).first
  @user_follower = current_user.user_followers.new(follower: @friend)
else
  flash[:error] = "Friend required"
end

end
```

I have the associantions set up correctly I think

Comment: You should probably call `save` somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting? Try `user_followers.create`.

Comment: the ajax request don't give errors. it's just don't save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a record I assume that you've set up your `teste` route as `POST`. If this is the case you'll have to add `method: :post` to your `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "Add friend", teste_user_follower_path(:params => @friend.id), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'btn' %>
```

It also doesn't look like you're actually saving the record anywhere. You're calling `new` but never calling `save`. If you want to do both at once you can use `create`

```
def teste
  if params[:query]
    @friend = User.where(id: params[:query]).first
    @user_follower = current_user.user_followers.create(follower: @friend)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Friend required"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually creating anything in your code.
Here is the documentation about associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

You should do something like:

```
@user_follower = current_user.user_followers.create(follower: @friend)
```